# Replace Line in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Estou criando uma aplicação em C# que utilizando o `Replace()`, eu consigo substituir uma palavra específica por outra em todo o arquivo, mas eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer esse Replace em apenas uma linha especifica.

Quero que o código localize a linha e depois faça o `Replace()` apenas nessa linha especifica sem prejudicar o resto do arquivo.

Comment: Atualizei! Tentei ser mais claro e objetivo, espero ter conseguido explicar melhor o meu problema

Comment: Com regex em uma linha, substitui a palavra linha por row na linha 7: `Regex.Replace(texto_de_entrada, "(?<=^([^\n]+\n){6}[^\r]*)linha(?=[^\r]*.*)", "row", RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Answer (score 1):

É possível se você tem como saber qual é a linha 7. Claro, desde que não tenha possibilidade de confusão com outra partes. Você trocou tudo para `.` e na linha 7 voltará de `.` para `,`. Mas vamos dizer que já tinha algo com `.` ali antes de trocar `,` para `.`, esse `.` que já estava lá virará `,`. É o que deseja? Se for, ok. Se não há possibilidade de ter um `.` anterior, ok, pode fazer.

Se não for possível ainda pode fazer linha por linha e pulando a linha 7. Mas cuidado se for fazer vários `replace()` terá um monte de alocação de memória. EM certas aplicações isso não é problema, mas tenha consciência que haverá pressão no *garbage collector* e em casos extremos pode haver exaustão de memória. Mesmo com um `replace()` háverá um pequena pressão, hoje tem técnicas para fazer isso de forma mais eficiente, mas neste caso provavelmente é preocupação excessiva.

Em última caso poderia fazer manualmente analisando cada caractere, mas se não souber fazer terá performance ruim.

Comment: Amigo, no caso a linha 7 tem sempre uma informação "7252" seguido pelo endereço do Windows com a localização de um arquivo PNG (imagem). Tipo: 7252 - c:/diretório/face.png
Então acho de como se trata de ser sempre um endereço do Windows não se tem vírgula pq não pode usar. 

No caso a ferramenta que estou criando entra o arquio txt e substitui todos os "," po"r ." Nesse caso a linha 7 permanece intacta por não ter virgulas. Depois disso tenho outro botão que faz o processo inverso, e nisso acaba modificando a linha 7 e é nesse processo que quero preservar essa linha

Comment: Pra mim a pergunta começou perder o sentido agora.

Comment: Desculpa, acho que não estou explicando o meu problema corretamente, mas basicamente eu gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de fazer o Replace em apenas uma linha específica? Se sim, como? Fiz algumas pesquisas mas não encontrei nada específico para apenas uma determinada linha